# PostgreSQL Query Cache - closing connection unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, caching, postgresql-9.0

```
<?php
$c = pg_connect( $connectionString, PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW );

$queries = array (
        "SELECT COUNT(*) AS data FROM articles",
        "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE visible = TRUE",
        "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE visible = FALSE",
        "SELECT * FROM types WHERE visible = TRUE"
);

foreach ( $queries as $query ) {
        $res = @pg_query( $c, $query );
        if ( empty( $res ) ) {
                echo "[ERR] " . pg_last_error( $c ) . "\n";
        } else {
                echo "[OK]\n";
        }
}
```

The snippet of code above is generating for the first time this:

```
[OK]
[OK]
[OK]
[OK]
```

but for the second time this:

```
[OK]
[OK]
[ERR] server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
[ERR] server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

This means that some cached queries cause a problem. We tried to change the order of quires, but it didn't help. Only simple queries like `SELECT 1+8`, which are probably not cached always run well.

Similar problem can be simulated using psql and probably any other language driver (not only PHP).

All troubles came up when we installed [PostgreSQL Query Cache](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1296/).

Should the query cache be configured somehow not behave this way?

Our config files are here:
http://pastebin.com/g2dBjba0 – pcqd_hba.conf
http://pastebin.com/X9Y3zrjx – pcqd.conf

Comment: `PostgreSQL` or `Postgres` for short. There is no "Postgre". [More here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Postgres).

Comment: Have you tried using PDO pgsql driver?

Comment: As I told, even with the original psql (shell tool for PostgreSQL) it behave the same. It doesn't matter which driver I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you have a bug in the PostgreSQL Query Cache which is causing segfaults in the backend.  Your best solution is to uninstall this add-on.